# Javascript onblur event message won't disappear

Tags: javascript

update: the onblur message disappears for username but not for password. Anyone can point out why?

---

I'm a novice. I came across `onblur` and used it in my html page, everything is fine but for one field the message won't go away even the values are corrected. The other fields work just fine and this one is bothering me for a few hours and I can't for the life of me figure out what's wrong. Someone, please point out what have I done wrong.

JS Code:

```
function checkUsername(field) {
    var x = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var regex = /^[A-Za-z0-9~@#$&_]*$/;
    document.getElementById("uname").innerText =
        (field.value === "") ? "username can't be empty" : "";
    if (!regex.test(x)) {
        document.getElementById("uname").innerHTML = "Enter a valid username";
    }
}

function checkPass(field) {
    var x = document.getElementById("passw").value;
    var regex = /^[a-z0-9]+$/;

    if (x.length < 5) {
        document.getElementById("pw").innerHTML = "Min of 5 characters needed for Passphrase";
    } else if (field.value.length > 10) {
        document.getElementById("pw").innerHTML = "Max characters for Passphrase is 10 characters";
    } else if (!regex.test(x)) {
        document.getElementById("pw").innerHTML = "Enter a valid Passphrase";
    }
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<label for="username">Username: </label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" onblur="checkUsername(this);" placeholder="username">
<font color='red'>
    <strong>
        <p id="uname"></p>
    </strong>
</font>

<label for="password">Password: </label>
<input type="password" id="passw" name="passw" onblur="checkPass(this);" placeholder="passphrase">
<font color='red'>
    <strong>
        <p id="pw"></p>
    </strong>
</font>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line in your `checkUsername` function clears the div if there was no error:

```
document.getElementById("uname").innerText = (field.value === "") ? "username can't be empty" : "";
```

This is why the div becomes empty when a success case is entered. If the value of the text input is not `""` then, the error div get's it;s innerHTML to `""`. This is not done for the `checkPass` method and the older error value stays even if the value is corrected to be a valid one.

So as stated by @vishu, you can add an extra else in your `checkPass` method to clear the div if no errors were found. OR you can just set the error div to empty before evaluating for errors like you have done in your `checkUsername` method.

```
function checkPass(field) {
    var x = document.getElementById("passw").value;
    var regex = /^[a-z0-9]+$/;
    var pw = document.getElementById("pw");

    // Clear older errors if needed
    pw.innerHTML = '';

    if (x.length < 5) {
        pw.innerHTML = "Min of 5 characters needed for Passphrase";
    } else if (field.value.length > 10) {
        pw.innerHTML = "Max characters for Passphrase is 10 characters";
    } else if (!regex.test(x)) {
        pw.innerHTML = "Enter a valid Passphrase";
    }
}
```

So to answer your question, divs don't get automatically cleared. You will have to do it explicitly via JS if you want to clear it (like you have in your `checkUsername` function)

Comment: Thanks. I completely ignored that. Now i get it... Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

In the javascript function use one more else condition so that if everything is fine it will blank the message text:-

```
function checkPass(field) {
    var x = document.getElementById("passw").value;
    var regex = /^[a-z0-9]+$/;
     var pw =  document.getElementById("pw")
    if (x.length < 5)
    {
        pw.innerHTML = "Min of 5 characters needed for Passphrase";
    }

    else if (field.value.length > 10)
    {
        pw.innerHTML = "Max characters for Passphrase is 10 characters";
    }
    else if(!regex.test(x))
    {
        pw.innerHTML = "Enter a valid Passphrase";
    }
    else{
       pw.innerHTML = '';
   }
}
```

Comment: If you're stuck in the second `else if`, it means that your regex is not matching. With this regex you are saying "input may only contain letters and numbers; no whitespaces - nothing else, even". If you type "aaaaaa" and you use the example above, the warning message should disappear.

Comment: Also, you are passing a `field` argument to your function, but then you never use it. It could also be that your `x` variable contains the value of a wrong field - namely not the field that you pass to your function in the `field` argument.

Comment: bcz if u got error on first time and u corrected it the error message will not disappear bcz there is no event to do that blank

Comment: The else part handles the case where the input had already caused an error and div was filled with an error text. If the text is corrected in the field (after first causing an error), the previously set error message is never removed. This likely happening for all your fields. Try: 1) selecting input 2) Entering a failing case 3) Select another input 4) select previous input 5) Correct value. Expcted result: Ther error does not get cleared

Comment: @minitauros the regex is working just fine and yes, i just need alphanumeric password. the message won't disappear until and unless i keep a blank innerHTML as directed by vishu but i just want to know why is this happening to only this field because the message disappeared just fine for the above other fields

Comment: @vishu i used the same code for some other fields too and the message disappeared when i corrected the values

Comment: @ChiragRavindra but the error got cleared to some fields and that made me wonder why it won't clear to this part of code

Comment: @SameerAhmad the code you have shared looks like it works for only one field. (I say this because all the errors are being put into a single div witth the id `pw`) Can you please update your question to show us how the other fields are setup? Maybe then we can see why it works in one case but not the other.

Comment: @SameerAhmad are you sure you have only UNIQUE id value in your html?

Comment: @ChiragRavindra I have updated the code with another field for which the message disappears

Comment: @LelioFaieta yes

Comment: @ChiragRavindra any thoughts?

Comment: @SameerAhmad I have responded with another answer to avoid cluttering this comment thread. This answer is still valid for the reasons described in the comments above..